# Import org.eclipse.search.ui package throws exception

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm developping an rcp 3.x app.

My goal : i want to use the eclipse command "org.eclipse.search.ui.openFileSearchPage" (this command makes a "file search dialog" appear) in my rcp app.

The problem : to be able to use this command in my app, i guess i have to import the package "org.eclipse.search.ui". But when i import this package, a problem occurs (when running the exported product, but when i run the product under Eclipse as an Eclipse application, there is no problem). The error in the log file is the following :

> !SESSION 2015-11-02 10:44:57.593
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=unknown java.version=1.8.0_66-internal
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=linux,
>   ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=fr_FR Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk
>   -arch x86 -consoleLog
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.607 !MESSAGE One or
>   more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints
>   are not resolved: !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-11-02
>   10:44:59.608 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jface.text_3.10.0.v20150603-1752.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jface.text 2 0 2015-11-02
>   10:44:59.609 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.swt_[3.103.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0
>   2015-11-02 10:44:59.610 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.ide_3.11.0.v20150825-2158.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.ide 2 0 2015-11-02
>   10:44:59.611 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.ui_[3.106.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.ide 2 0
>   2015-11-02 10:44:59.612 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.services_2.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.ide 2 0
>   2015-11-02 10:44:59.613 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_[1.3.0,2.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.ui.ide 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.615 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts_[1.3.100,2.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.616 !MESSAGE
>   Bundle
>   initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.swt.gtk_1.0.1.v20150708-1529.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.swt.gtk 2 0 2015-11-02
>   10:44:59.617 !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.osgi.service.event_1.3.1. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.swt.gtk 2
>   0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.618 !MESSAGE Missing host
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.10.0. !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2
>   0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.619 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.100.v20150402-1551.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state 2 0
>   2015-11-02 10:44:59.620 !MESSAGE Missing host org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.0.
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.620 !MESSAGE
>   Bundle
>   initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.trace_1.0.300.v20150220-1252.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.trace 2 0 2015-11-02
>   10:44:59.620 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.11.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi
>   2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.620 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.6.0.v20150318-1505/
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry 2 0 2015-11-02
>   10:44:59.621 !MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability:
>   osgi.ee;
>   filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry 2 0
>   2015-11-02 10:44:59.621 !MESSAGE Missing host
>   org.eclipse.equinox.registry_[3.6.0,3.7.0). !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.621 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.forms_3.6.200.v20150506-2029.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.forms 2 0 2015-11-02
>   10:44:59.621 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt_0.11.100. !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0
>   2015-11-02 10:44:59.621 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.views_3.8.0.v20150422-0725.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.views 2 0 2015-11-02
>   10:44:59.621 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.11.0,4.0.0).
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.640 !MESSAGE The
>   following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see
>   the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists: !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.641 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   com.xool.test_1.0.0.201511021038 [3] was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2
>   com.xool.test 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.642 !MESSAGE Missing imported
>   package org.eclipse.search.ui_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0
>   2015-11-02 10:44:59.643 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.compare_3.5.600.v20150420-1449 [16] was not resolved.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.compare 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.644 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.8.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.compare 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.645 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.ide_[3.3.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.compare 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.646 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.ui.views_[3.2.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.compare 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.647 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.compare 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.648 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.editors_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.compare 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.649 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.forms_[3.2.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY
>   1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.650 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.jface.text_3.10.0.v20150603-1752 [71] was not resolved.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jface.text 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.650
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.swt_[3.103.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.651 !MESSAGE
>   Bundle org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_3.7.200.v20140625-1835 [73] was
>   not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0
>   2015-11-02 10:44:59.651 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.651 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.compare_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.651 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.ui_[3.4.100,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY
>   1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.651 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.search_3.10.0.v20150318-0856 [75] was not resolved.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.search 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.651 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.ide_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.search 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.651 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.search 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.651 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.search 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.651 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.forms_[3.4.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY
>   2 org.eclipse.search 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.652 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.652 !MESSAGE
>   Bundle org.eclipse.team.ui_3.7.200.v20150203-1452 [78] was not
>   resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.team.ui 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.652
>   !MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle
>   org.eclipse.ui.ide_[3.3.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.team.ui 2 0
>   2015-11-02 10:44:59.652 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.compare_[3.3.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.team.ui 2 0
>   2015-11-02 10:44:59.652 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.ui.forms_[3.3.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.team.ui 2
>   0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.652 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.3.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.team.ui
>   2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.652 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.ui.editors_[3.3.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0
>   2015-11-02 10:44:59.652 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.ui.editors_3.9.0.v20150213-1939 [81] was not resolved.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.editors 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.652
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.ide_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.editors 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.652
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.8.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.editors 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.652
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor_[3.7.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.652 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.ui.forms_3.6.200.v20150506-2029 [82] was not resolved.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.forms 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.657 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt_0.11.100. !SUBENTRY
>   1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.657 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.ui.ide_3.11.0.v20150825-2158 [83] was not resolved.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.ide 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.657 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui_[3.106.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.ui.ide 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.657 !MESSAGE Missing
>   optionally required bundle org.eclipse.ui.views_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.ide 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.657 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.ide 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.657 !MESSAGE
>   Missing optionally required bundle org.eclipse.ui.forms_[3.3.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.ide 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.657 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.core.services_2.0.0. !SUBENTRY
>   2 org.eclipse.ui.ide 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.657 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts_[1.3.100,2.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.ide 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.657 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_[1.3.0,2.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.657 !MESSAGE
>   Bundle org.eclipse.ui.trace_1.0.300.v20150220-1252 [85] was not
>   resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.trace 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.658
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.11.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi
>   2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.658 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.ui.views_3.8.0.v20150422-0725 [86] was not resolved.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.views 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.658 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.11.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.658 !MESSAGE
>   Bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor_3.9.100.v20141023-1946 [88]
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor 2 0
>   2015-11-02 10:44:59.658 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.8.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0
>   2015-11-02 10:44:59.658 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.6.0.v20150318-1505
>   [97] was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry 2 0 2015-11-02
>   10:44:59.658 !MESSAGE Missing host
>   org.eclipse.equinox.registry_[3.6.0,3.7.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry 2 0 2015-11-02
>   10:44:59.658 !MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability:
>   osgi.ee;
>   filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.658 !MESSAGE
>   Bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.swt.gtk_1.0.1.v20150708-1529 [98] was not
>   resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.swt.gtk 2 0 2015-11-02
>   10:44:59.658 !MESSAGE Missing host
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.10.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.swt.gtk 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.658 !MESSAGE Missing
>   imported package org.osgi.service.event_1.3.1. !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.658 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.100.v20150402-1551 [101] was
>   not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state 2 0
>   2015-11-02 10:44:59.658 !MESSAGE Missing host org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.0.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-11-02 10:44:59.659 !MESSAGE
>   Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.RuntimeException: Application
>   "com.xool.test.application" could not be found in the registry. The
>   applications available are: org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner,
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application,
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.GenTopic,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.app.error.    at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

I don't manage to find the solution... Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: If you are using a plugins based .product file then every plugin required must be listed in the .product file. For a features based .product file the features must contain all the required plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You need to revise your plug-in dependencies. It seems the search plug-in needs some other plug-ins to work properly (jface.text, etc.). 
See your stacktrace: it mentions those in "was not resolved" or "Missing required"
Add the required bundles to your feature.xml. That should do the trick.
It might work when you start your plug-in from within Eclipse, because all those bundles are part of the target platform you are developing against. But at runtime those bundles arent neccessarily available.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Should i add required-bundles in the manifest.mf file of the plugin, or in the list of plugins of the product (or both)?

Comment: The product should normally be based on a feature, I would assume.So, I would add the bundles to your feature.

Comment: No my product is based on plugins... Why sould it be based on features?

Comment: You are not obliged to do, but I would personally think a product consists of features, which combined assemble the product itself. A feature consists of one or more plug-ins providing functionality to form a feature.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked all the dependencies, and all the plugins required are in the list in the .product file, so i really don't understand what is wrong... Could it be possible that it is because of wrong plugin version? What about the "Missing imported package org.eclipse.search.ui_0.0.0" : isn't it strange, i mean about the version 0.0.0, could this be the problem?

Comment: Check you stacktrace: See the plug in dependencies as a tree you must follow through all branches and leafs. Your bundle requires A, A requires B, B requires C, etc. Usually you shouldnt be forced to go further than 2 levels

Comment: Click the 'Add Required' button on the Contents page of the .product editor to have Eclipse add all the required plugins